# Using "type": "module" in Node.js not importing file

Tags: node.js

I am using "type": "module" in Node.js and am unable to import my file.
I have this file structure

[image]

My index.js file

```
import express from 'express';
import tourRouter from './routes/tourRoutes';


const app = express();
app.use(express.json());


app.use('/api/v1/tours', tourRouter);
```

My tourRoutes.js

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';


const tours = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`../dev-data/data/tours-simple.json`));


const getAllTours = (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({
    status: 'success',
    results: tours.length,
    data: { tours },
  });
};


const router = express.Router();


router.route('/').get(getAllTours);


module.exports = router;
```

Yet the file won't import

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module '...\api\routes\tourRoutes' imported from ...\api\index.js

What is truly a basic concept has really got me stumped. The code looks correct to me. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per Node.js docs for [Mandatory file extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions):

> A file extension must be provided when using the import keyword to resolve relative or absolute specifiers. Directory indexes (e.g. './startup/index.js') must also be fully specified.

To fix your problem add the `.js` file extension like so:

```js
import express from 'express';
import {router as tourRouter} from './routes/tourRoutes.js'; //< .js extension added
```

Then you need to use the `export` keyword in the `tourRoutes.js` file like so:

```js
export const router = express.Router(); //< Add export keyword
router.route('/').get(getAllTours);
//module.exports = router; //< Delete this line
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `tourRouter` found in the tourRoutes.js file.

You have exported `router`. Change the `router` as `tourRouter`

```
const tourRouter = express.Router();

tourRouter.route('/').get(getAllTours);

module.exports = tourRouter;
```

This will resolve the issue.

Comment: This will not solve the problem and may give a `SyntaxError: The requested module './routes/tourRoutes.js' does not provide an export named 'tourRouter'`. That is because `module.exports` is for CommonJS and OP is using ES Modules which means they need to use `export` keyword.

Comment: I got the point. Incase of `module.exports ` we need to use  `const tourRouter = require("./routes/tourRoutes.js")` in `index.js` file. This will work fine, won't it?

Comment: It would work fine if using CommonJS module yes but OP is using ES Modules so there is different syntax and they can't really be mixed.